# Alert simulation on vSphere 5.5

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, vmware-vcenter

Is there any way to simulate an alert (to test alarm actions) on an vmware vSphere esxi 5.5 infrastructure?

My research seems that a "test" was available on some older versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there is a direct way to do this in the vCenter clients (I've searched for it previously as well).

To confirm alarm actions are triggering, you can manually adjust an alarm's thresholds so that it triggers the 'failed' state, and then change the threshold back to its original value afterwards.

We commonly use the *Datastore usage on disk* alarm for this, ie. set the threshold low enough that at least one datastore will activate the alarm. You can find some other suggestions for harmless alarms at https://communities.vmware.com/message/2048259.